# position QScrollBar in QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

How can i track the position QScrollBar in QScrollArea?
I tried this function but it didn't work.

I want to do database work when the slider reaches 2/3 of the available information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to fully answer without seeing your code, but the [value property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) will give you the scroll bar (slider) value (based on your defined minimum and maximum). Of course, you're responsible for setting the minimum and maximum. Sounds like you want, for example, a range of 0 to 100 and a change when the value reaches 67.

Also, if you want, you can set the tracking property if you want to be automatically informed of changes to the scroll bar position.

Comment: I could not find how to just set the function to track the change in the position of the slider

Comment: Again, it's hard to answer without seeing code, but if you enable tracking, the slider will emit a valueChanged() signal to which you can connect, and when it reports back 67 or more, you can do your database work.